# Error in NextJS handler after updating all packages(Next-Connect error)

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-connect

````
import cookieSession from 'cookie-session';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

import nc from 'next-connect';

import { error } from 'next/dist/build/output/log';
import passport from './passport';
import { trustProxyMiddleware } from './trust-proxy-middleware';

export interface Request extends NextApiRequest {
    // Passport adds these to the request object
    logout: () => void;
    logIn: (user: Express.User, done: (err?: any) => void) => void;
    user?: Express.User;
    protocol?: string;
}

const COOKIE_SECRET = process.env.COOKIE_SECRET;

/**
 * Create an API route handler with next-connect and all the necessary middlewares
 *
 * @example
 * ```ts
 * export default handler().get((req, res) => { ... })
 * ```
 */
function handler() {
    if (!COOKIE_SECRET) throw new Error(`Please add COOKIE_SECRET to your .env.local file!`);

    return (
        nc<Request, NextApiResponse>({
            onError: (err: any, _: any, res: NextApiResponse) => {
                error(err);
                res.status(500).end(err.toString());
            },
        })
            // In order for authentication to work on Vercel, req.protocol needs to be set correctly.
            // However, Vercel's and Netlify's reverse proxy setup breaks req.protocol, which the custom
            // trustProxyMiddleware fixes again.
            .use(trustProxyMiddleware)
            .use(
                cookieSession({
                    name: 'session',
                    keys: [COOKIE_SECRET],
                    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 30,
                    // Do not change the lines below, they make cy.auth() work in e2e tests
                    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && !process.env.INSECURE_AUTH,
                    signed: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && !process.env.INSECURE_AUTH,
                }),
            )
            .use(passport.initialize())
            .use(passport.session())
    );
}

export default handler;
````

now returns this error:
[{
"resource": "XXXX/server/api-route.ts",
"owner": "typescript",
"code": "2349",
"severity": 8,
"message": "This expression is not callable.\n  Type 'typeof import("/XXXX/node_modules/next-connect/dist/types/index")' has no call signatures.",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 32,
"startColumn": 3,
"endLineNumber": 32,
"endColumn": 5
}]
Where i'm trying to use nc.

Used to work. I updated all packages and could fix all problems except for this one.